# How to get place_id from longitude and latitude in google Map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

I can get place Id by using [This Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder). But problem is this is based on location search. I want to get place_id using draggeble  marker so I can't use above link. I am moving the marker on Google Map, So how I can get place_id on Map.

Through marker.getPosition() we can get the latitude and longitude. So I want to know the **place_id** through latitude and longitude. How can I get, please tell me

```
latitude=marker.getPosition().lat();               
longitude=marker.getPosition().lng();
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `google.maps.Geocoder` for 
`Reverse Geocoding` as explained here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

You will recieve data containing `results[1].place_id`.

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;

latitude=marker.getPosition().lat();               
longitude=marker.getPosition().lng();
var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latitude), lng: parseFloat(longitude)};

geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[1]) {
        console.log(results[1].place_id);
      } else {
        window.alert('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
```

Comment: I am wondering: why would you use the second result and not `results[0]`?

Answer (score 10):

You can either use the Geocoder API to send request, or simply send the HTTP request to the web service behind.

Your sample request:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=**lat**,**lng**&key=**YOUR_API_KEY**

You can then easily parse the JSON object by Javascript JSON.parse().

Answer (score 3):

I got new way to solve this issue. Here  I have used google http service to get total information of location based on longitude and latitude. You just need to pass latitude and longitude in url and your api key (ex : latlng=21.1497409, 79.08747970000002 & key=YOUR API KEY). Here is my get service in ExampleService Class

```
 getService(url) {

    return this.http.get(url).map((data: any) => data.json())

}
```

this you can put anywhere you want and just call below service from component where you need location data

```
this._exampleService.getService("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=21.1497409, 79.08747970000002&key=YOUR API KEY").subscribe(getplaceData => {
            var placeDataDest: any;
            placeDataDest = getplaceData;
            console.log("i got place id yeee " + placeDataDest['results'][0]['place_id']);
            console.log("i got place details yeee " + placeDataDest['results']);
        });
```

hope you will find this useful